# Python: How to group elements in the list and get sum of groups

Tags: python, list

I want to group list digits by their value and calculate sum of each group. Basically, it looks this way:

input:

```
list = [0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0]
```

OUT (which i want to get):

```
newList = [0,2,0,1,0,4,0]
```

Any ideas how to acheive this in Python?

Thanks

Comment: [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
s = [0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0]
final_s = [sum(b) for _, b in itertools.groupby(s)]
```

Output:

```
[0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0]
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is recursive approach with one loop.

```
list1 = [0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0]

final_=[]
def recursive(lst):
  track = []
  if not lst:
    return 0
  else:
    for i,j in enumerate(lst):
      try:


        if lst[i]==lst[i+1]:

          track.append((lst[i],lst[i+1]))
        else:
          track.append(lst[i])
          final_.append(track)
          return recursive(lst[i+1:])
      except IndexError:
        final_.append([i])
recursive(list1)

print(list(map(lambda x:0 if 0 in x else len(x),final_)))
```

output:

```
[0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ist = [0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0]
a=[[]]
[a[-1].append(e) if e==ist[c-1] else a.append([e]) for c,e in enumerate(ist)]
new_list=[sum(l) for l in a]
```

Doesn't need libraries. Output:

```
[0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0]
```